# How to make the background picture responsive to the screensize?

Tags: background-image

I have a body background image, that is fixed in the background and the containers scroll in front of it. The problem is that the picture keeps being magnified according to the size of the screen. When I want it to be fixed.

I have most everything. this is the code, any thoughts? :

```
body {

    background:url('http://www.markrehnstrom.com/img/bg-img.jpg');
    background-image: url('http://www.markrehnstrom.com/img/bg-img.jpg');
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover 100%;
    background-origin: content-box;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    float:left;


}

.background-img:after{
    background-position:left;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `background-size` to a fixed value, like `80px 60px`, or whatever you need.

If you do this, the size of the image will remain fixed no matter how much you change the window size.

eg: `background-size: 80px 60px;`

Also, check out this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: When I do the suggested, a white background color appears in the right side. Any other techniques?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot? It'll help to see what exactly your problem is, as your html isn't here either...

Comment: Also, considering that your picture has a black background, you could change `background-color: black;`... Just try it.

Comment: In the end, I gave up and created a bigger image that accommodated the screen problem. I tried your resolutions but none really worked this time, I appreciate your time!